# Care for an indoor hyacinth after blooming

Tags: indoors, plant-care, bulbs, hyacinth

I have a hyacinth planted in a pot indoors. From what I have read, I should cut the stalk and let the leaves die naturally. So I cut the flower stalk but it seems now after about two months, the leaves are still alive.

I water it almost every day. Where I live the plant occasionally gets sunlight. This is due to most of the time the weather is overcast.

Should I continue to water it every day or let the plant dry?

Possibly I would like the bulb to flower next year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of things - when you bought your hyacinth bulb, was it a prepared, pre treated one, sold specially for growing indoors? Or was it just an ordinary outdoor one? It's usual to buy a prepared one for indoor growing, to ensure they flower in late winter rather than waiting for late spring, as they naturally do, so the fact yours has already finished flowering probably indicates it was a prepared bulb. As such, it will not perform in the same way this coming winter, and won't flower till late spring, so the best thing to do with it now is to plant it outdoors and let it revert to its natural growth habit.

I'd just add that, while the foliage is present, that is the time to feed the bulb, so that it can store enough energy to create a good flower for next year. If you have space outdoors to plant it, and it's cold where you are now, take the opportunity to add some fertilizer when you water, while it's still got leaves, then transfer it outdoors after hardening off (see [What is 'Hardening Off'?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/what-is-hardening-off))

Comment: Congrats on your hyperlink skills, how far you've come!

Comment: Erm, well thanks, but I haven't come that far - I can see some people just have a word highlighted in blue that leads to a link, no idea how to do that!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's prepared as you said.